# My unit test case is not covering if statement

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

the following is my function in ts file:

```
routeToIndividualPortal(sessionToken: string) {
    let redirectUrl = this.relayState;
    console.log("Pre-source-check Indivual URL : " + redirectUrl);
    let url = "";
    if(redirectUrl.includes(this.envSvc.environment.peakAppId)){
      url = this.sessionTokenUrl + sessionToken + "&redirectUrl=" + this.relayState;
      console.log("peak url : " + url);
    }
    else{
      url = this.sessionTokenUrl + sessionToken + "&redirectUrl=" +this.individualLoginRouterUrl + "&requestedUrl=" + redirectUrl
      console.log("C4 url : " + url);
    }
    console.log("window.location.href : " + url);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

and the following is my test case which is passing but its not covering the if part as its only covering else part:

```
it('test routeToIndividualPortal', () => {
    envSvc = new EnvironmentService(window);
    envSvc.environment = new Environment();
    envSvc.environment.peakAppId = 'RelayState=0oartebbbbs4KnvOK0h7';
    let sessionToken = "randomstuffljbn";
    let redirectUrl = "";
    expect(component.relayState).toEqual(redirectUrl);

    spyOn(window, 'open');
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.routeToIndividualPortal(sessionToken);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.loginInvalid).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

and I don't know what am I missing here so if someone knows where I am wrong then it will be great help!

Answer (score 1):

Without a running example on something like stackblitz, it's hard to be sure as we can't see exactly what everything is set to. The first thing you should do is to run the test in the debugger and set a break statement on the if statement. Or even just use console.log to log out all the values.

But based on the code you have posted: these lines in your tests

```
let redirectUrl = "";
expect(component.relayState).toEqual(redirectUrl);
```

suggests that relayState is an empty string. So in you function

```
let redirectUrl = this.relayState
```

will set redirectUrl to an empty string and therefore

```
redirectUrl.includes(this.envSvc.environment.peakAppId)
```

will always been false.